# string replace \n or <br/> with &#xD; in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Hi i have TextField in as3 in that i assigning the html value like

```
var TFhtmlText:String = "<span class='Header'>The value need to be 25 percentage  \n and percentage be 50 percent.</span>"

 txtField.htmlText = TFhtmlText;
```

from the above i need line break after 25 percentage for that i used `<br/>` but i got unwanted spaces between line break, so that now i used  `&#xD`; for linebreak this is working fine , so i need to replace this (`&#xD;`) character where `\n` is present .. i tried with

```
TFhtmlText = TFhtmlText.split('\n').join('&#xD;')
 txtField.htmlText = TFhtmlText;


TFhtmlText=TFhtmlText.replace(/\n/g, "&#xD;");
```

But not working ....how can i achieve it

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Next time please format your code correctly, it's difficult to read.

Assuming I read it correctly, you want to write your string as follows. Replace the \n with 
 and remove the whitespace around it.

```
var TFhtmlText:String = "The value need to be 25 percentage<br/>and percentage be 50 percent."
txtField.htmlText = TFhtmlText;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
var my_str:String = new String(TFhtmlText);
my_str = my_str.split('\n').join('&#xD;');
txtField.htmlText = my_str;
```

Comment: Its EXACTLY that in the question

Comment: @Paranav I don't understand what you mean

Comment: In the question, he wrote `TFhtmlText = TFhtmlText.split('\n').join('&#xD;'); txtField.htmlText = TFhtmlText;`. In your answer, you changed TFhtmlText to my_str, added another line of code thats it

Comment: I think he edited his question adding my sample of code there. Anyway! Mistakes happen :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason why it doesn't work.

```
tfHtmlText = tfHtmlText.split(' \n ').join('&#xD;')
txtField.htmlText = tfHtmlText;
```

Or, if you want to put `<br />` then

```
tfHtmlText = tfHtmlText.split(' \n ').join('<br />')
txtField.htmlText = tfHtmlText;
```

Notice the space before and after the `\n` in the parameter for `split()`